# declare variables in sql ce

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce

I am tryin to get records from a table within a month in sql compact edition.
Here is the sql query I know:

```
DECLARE @startDate as DATETIME, @EndDate as DATETIME

@startDate = GetDate();
@ENdDate = DATEADD(m,1,@startDate)

select * from table where (columnname between @startdate and @enddate)
```

I know that you have to send one script at a time, but how can you declare variables in sql ce(I guess it doesn't accept declare)?

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is very late for this question, but hope it will be useful for someone.

You can't declare some variable in SQL CE, because just one statement can be used per command. As ErikEJ said in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/402d0d8f-5ca4-4bc4-9b4b-4482c60e21b7/declaring-variables-in-sql-ce?forum=sqlce).

You need to refactor your script to one big statement, if it's possible!

I will be very happy to hear a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL-CE, but I think you're missing some `Set` statements. <strike>Try this</strike>:

```
DECLARE @startDate as DATETIME, @EndDate as DATETIME

Set @startDate = GetDate();
Set @ENdDate = DATEADD(m,1,@startDate)

select * from table where (columnname between @startdate and @enddate)
```

**Update**
See the [Using Parameters in Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226067%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL CE reference from MSDN. You are correct in that Declare is not a valid keyword, so you'll need to the query as a parameterized version from the application itself.

`select * from table where (columnname between ? and ?)`

Comment: DECLARE is not allowed in SQL CE

Comment: @alice7 after reading more about it, SQL-CE is pretty interesting, but very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at post [How do I populate a SQL Server Compact database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528416/how-do-i-populate-a-sql-server-compact-database/5528476#5528476) 
and see if tool referenced there may help you.

Comment: Actually what I thought is to use something like this: GetAll records from database(not a wise idea). Then use list.FindAll(Object => (Object.Date < DateTime.Now.AddMOnths(1) && Object.Date > DateTime.Now)); which would give the exact result. Thnx for your suggestion nikadim

Answer (score 0):

If you call it through an application (I'm not sure how you read the data)

Prepare your query just like this:

```
select * from table where (columnname between ? and ?)
```

but I'm not sure if you can use the between keyword. may be you need to change this.

then you need to add your SqlCeParameter objects like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("p1", SqlDbType.DateTime, myDate));
```